# ROR: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have not idea on which file is having this issue.

```
bundle exec rake db:create --trace
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:90: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::VERSION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:92: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1188: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1267: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1446: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::DIRECTORY_TERM
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1541: warning: previous definition of DIRECTORY_TERM was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1448: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::SYSCASE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1543: warning: previous definition of SYSCASE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1501: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1596: warning: previous definition of OPT_TABLE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1555: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LOW_METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1650: warning: previous definition of LOW_METHODS was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1562: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1657: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.4, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
(erb):26:in `<main>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:172:in `database_configuration'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bugsnag-6.7.3/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:18:in `execute_with_bugsnag'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:237:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:212:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'


    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
    /usr/local/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
    /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

    Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
(erb):26:in `<main>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `eval'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/erb.rb:876:in `result'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:172:in `database_configuration'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bugsnag-6.7.3/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:18:in `execute_with_bugsnag'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:237:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:212:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
        /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
    /usr/local/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
    /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
```

Database.yml

```
PostgreSQL. Versions 7.4 and 8.x are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pcms_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pcms_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: # <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] %>
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the db config file?

Comment: Not 100% on this but would this work: `<%= Rails.application.secrets(params[:database][:password]) %>`?

Answer (score 1):

If your database.yml file looks like the same as you pasted, then please remove this

```
# <%= Rails.application.secrets[:database][:password] %>
```

from the test Env, keep the password blank as same as development,
Also comment the first line in the file

```
#PostgreSQL. Versions 7.4 and 8.x are supported.
```

Try this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pcms_development
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pcms_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

Comment: I removed the password to the test in the database.yml, also removed the first line from the database file. still having the same issue

Comment: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Comment: You have to create a new user "postgres" or something else but don't use root

Comment: Now that your https://github.com/t4mo/ample-admin-lite.git error is gone, you try to login to postgres manually and use the same credentials to connect from the Rails app.

Comment: $ bundle exec rake db:create (says Database 'pcms_development' already exists
Database 'pcms_test' already exists)

Comment: cool! that means you were able to run the DB rake tasks to create the databases.